# How to create a folder without an error using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: php, post, cakephp, microsoft-graph-api, content-type

I am trying to create a folder in my team's Sharepoint folder using CakePHP, but it says an error.
I tried several ways to post and call APIs, but everything didn't work.
My API is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/children
```

And I built this function below.

```
private function createNewFolder($folder_name)
{
    try {
        $http = new Client();
        $accessToken = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('accessToken');
        
        $data = [
            "name" => $folder_name,
            "folder" => "{ }",
            "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" => "rename"
        ];
        
        $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/children";
        
        $headers = [
            'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $accessToken, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
        ];

        return $http->post($url, json_encode($data), $headers)->getJson();
    } catch
    (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It says an error,

> "Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema."

Although it works using Postman, but it doesn't work in website.

I already allowed permissions including `Files.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All` in Active Directory.

Comment: Use a tool such as Fiddler to compare and contrast the contents of the HTTP requests generated by Postman and by PHP. Play spot the difference. Once you see a (meaningful) difference, you can adjust your PHP code accordingly to output the same thing. If you need help with that, show us the PostMan code.

Comment: It doesn't need to use `jason_encode` for the body? When I don't use jason_encode like ```return $http->post($url, $data, $headers)->getJson();```, then it says "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.". What should I do now?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 for OS and running xampp to serve localhost. Any points here?

Comment: If it's saying you need JSON then use JSON. I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion to remove that. Are you saying your postman version sends the data with a different content type? (I don't think your OS or WAMP version has any relation to the response you get from the remote server, btw)

Comment: Regarding to Postman, when I get Curl code, `json_encode` converts `$data` like ```CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\r\n  \"name\": \"FOLDER_NAME\",\r\n  \"folder\": { },\r\n  \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\": \"rename\"\r\n}"```. But actual encoded code is different result. So I think the main reason that I got the error is because of the difference of json data.

Comment: That's just manually encoded and escaped JSON. What is json_encode producing, by comparison?

Comment: The produced result is `{"name":"Folder_Name","folder":"{ }","@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"rename"}`. Any hint?

Comment: Those two pieces of JSON are equivalent. I don't think that's your issue

Comment: You can try getting the folder id using folder name by using this call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/ShivaFolder1`. You should use that id to create a folder which will looks like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01252UHI533QHIZLNDN5HLU3VAE7IRKDAM/children`. This worked for me according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). Creating folder API call may not support foldername. So you can try this work around.

Comment: And remove double quotes for flower braces({ }). May be this could be the reason for that error.

Comment: Hi hotcakedev, did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, but no. The parameter {} still in needs.

Comment: Have you tried it this way 
`$data = [
            "name" => $folder_name,
            "folder" => { },
            "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" => "rename"
        ];`

Comment: In PHP, it causes an error.

Comment: Ok. As @ADyson said please check in fiddler to see how the payload looks like and compare it with the [documented payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) and give a try modifying that in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this, the solution is painfully simple, Graph API doesn't like the default way PHP encodes JSON:

```
$array = [
    "name" => "FolderName",
    "folder" => []
];

var_dump(json_encode($array));
```

Will output:

```
string(33) "{"name":"FolderName","folder":[]}"
```

And that's how the SDK is programmed. The trouble is Graph API doesn't like square brackets for empty objects. It wants curly brackets. This can be achieved in PHP by adding a flag to the JSON encoding:

```
$array = [
    "name" => "FolderName",
    "folder" => []
];

var_dump(json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

This will output:

```
string(33) "{"name":"FolderName","folder":{}}"
```

Which is the format Graph API wants. But as the JSON encoding is done automatically by the SDK without the flag, we'll have to override it by encoding the array ourselves:

```
$response = $graph->setApiVersion("v1.0")
    ->createRequest("POST", "/drives/me/items/root/children")
    ->addHeaders([
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ])
    ->attachBody(json_encode([
        "name" => "FolderName",
        "folder" => []
    ], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT))
    ->execute();
```