# Can I get children using folder name and id in the same time using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: api, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to display folder and file list from a Sharepoint in my CakePHP web application.
Please review my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545783/how-to-create-a-folder-without-an-error-using-microsoft-graph-api?noredirect=1#comment114138119_64545783).

What I am going to do is to get children from a folder with id and also inner folder with name, in the same time, using Graph API.

I want to get list from an api like

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/items/{item-id}/children`

I am not sure if it is available and how to implement it.

At this moment, I can get children from a folder with its name.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/children`

And I can filter the response using query parameters like below.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/children/?$filter=id eq '{folder-id}'`

Can I get sub folder's children at this moment?

Any help?

Comment: You can get the folder details by using the id `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01252UHI533QHIZLNDN5HLU3VAE7IRKDAM/children` or by using Foldername like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/ShivaFolder1?$expand=children`. The expand query parameter will specify the same children present in the folder in the childern property. You can use any one of these. Looks like the second one suits your requirement :)-

Comment: Hey @Shiva-MSFTIdentity. Your comment is so helpful, but please read my question again. I asked how to use both folder name and folder id in the same time.

Comment: No, you cannot do it using both because both mean the same and that would through an error from MS Graph server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method. As @Shiva said, their properties are the same. You cannot use the folder name and folder ID at the same time. You can try the api provided by Shiva. I think it is a good method:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/{folder-name}?$expand=children
```

Comment: The reason why I am going to use folder id is that it is fixed even the actions like changing folder name, etc. So I could figure this out by using the folder id for item-id exactly inside deep path what I want.